# UIView and NSLayoutConstraint nil when called in another class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I want the .constant value changed for a constraint I have setup in storyboard.  Every time I try to set the variables to pass to an inout function I get nil.  Any help would be appreciated.  I will map out this problem below.

SpinningWheel.swift

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

 //
 // call function on WheelViewController to display alert that wheel spinning
 //
 var view: UIView = WheelViewController().genieBusyAlertView
 var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint = WheelViewController().genieBottomLayoutConstraint
 WheelViewController().wheelTappedWhileActive(&view, &constraint)
```

WheelViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet var genieBusyAlertView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var genieBottomLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 // the view or the constraint are referenced here, but they are in the storyboard.
}

func wheelTappedWhileActive(inout view: UIView, inout _ constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        constraint.constant = 251
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        }, completion: {(true) in

            //nothing here yet.
    })

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 3.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        constraint.constant = -100
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(view)
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {(true) in

            //nothing here yet
    })
}
```

I am trying to grab the UIView, genieBusyAlertView and the NSLayoutConstraint genieBottomLayoutConstraint in one class, pass them into the function on another class to update the constraint constant so it will animate.  Any help would be awesome.  Thanks in advance for any time and brain power you use on this problem.

Comment: FYI. I was able to animate this view and change the constant in the same class outside of a function...also I was successful in doing so after all subviews loaded...but unable to the way I need it to work.

Comment: How are you supposed to be so sure of "var view: UIView = WheelViewController().genieBusyAlertView" to work as you are referring WheelViewController reference from properly. WheelViewController will load new reference to WheelViewController and will not take account of genieBusyAlertView as the WheelViewController is not created from storyboard?

Comment: Great question @ldindu. So how do I run the function that is located in WheelViewController from the SpinningWheel class?  Every time I run it, inside that function it shows in debug that the UIView and the NSLayoutConstraint with IBOutlets set are nil.  How is that?

Comment: What is SpinningWheel, a view controller or a class?

Comment: What is SpinningWheel, a view controller or a view?